# what to do if my project has multiple html pages

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am pretty new to webpack, I just learned about webpack-dev-server and stuff like plugins. So here is my situation: I'm currently trying to develop a website that has a homepage and other pages as well, the Html code for these pages is ready and now I'm using webpack to bundle my js files. In order to be more efficient, I want to use the webpack dev-server because it enables auto-reloading whenever I make a change in my code, however I am a bit confused with the following: I know that I have to add my homepage as a plugin in my webpack.config.js file for it to be rendered on the fly with the bundle file as script. but what about the other pages? should I also add them in the array of plugins? will the bundle script be injected in their Html too? and in such a case how will webpack know which Html page to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a file with many files that I want to add.

**entry.js**

```
module.exports.html = {  
  index: "./sources/js/index.js",
  about: "./sources/js/about.js",
  contact: "./sources/js/contact.js"
};
```

In the webpack, this file is imported `const ENTRY = require ('./ entry.js');` and in the plugins section, I use this entry:

**base.config.js**

```
plugins: Object.keys(ENTRY.html).map(entryName => {
  const templateName = entryName === "contact" ? "kontakt" : entryName === "about" ? "o-mnie" : "index";
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    filename: `${templateName}.html`,
    template: `./sources/templates/${entryName}.pug`,
    file: require(`../sources/data/${entryName}.json`),
    chunks: [entryName],
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'
  });
})
```

Here you have the whole project with many pages -> [example](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-boilerplate/tree/master/webpack)